# Ломается программа на Express

Tags: node.js, express

Пишу P2P сеть на основе Express, в качестве эксперимента. Но почему-то при отправке данных в формате JSON используя встроенную функцию res.json() программа крашается с ошибкой ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END. Просьба помочь с нахождением источника проблемы и обьяснением как этого можно избежать.

```js
const express = require('express');
const os = require('os');
const app = express();
// Config
const port = 14050
let nodes = [];
let info = {
    "NetworkState":"Connecting",
    "OS":{
        "name": os.type(),
        "release": os.release(),
        "platform": os.platform()
    },
    "Node Configuration": {
        "hostname": os.hostname(),
        "port": port,
    }
};
// App
function format(seconds){
    function pad(s){
      return (s < 10 ? '0' : '') + s;
    }
    var hours = Math.floor(seconds / (60*60));
    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds % (60*60) / 60);
    var seconds = Math.floor(seconds % 60);
  
    return pad(hours) + ':' + pad(minutes) + ':' + pad(seconds);
  }
app.get("/ver", (req, res) => {
    let user_info = [
        {
            "node": process.version,
            "uptime": format(process.uptime())
        }
    ]
    if (res.writable === true) {res.write(res.json(user_info));}
});
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(info);
});
```

Comment: res.json уже пришет в стрим. res.write не нужен. И проверка на writable не нужна

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо.